# Python Pandas - How to Keep All Observations By Selector Variable When Data are in Long Form

Tags: python, pandas

I am working in Python 3.11.1. I have data like these stored in a Pandas Dataframe:

```
ID  Position    Select
1      A          0
2      B          1
2      C          0
3      B          0
3      C          0
4      A          1
5      A          0
```

Where some ID's are recorded in multiple rows, but others only appear in a single row. I need to subset this dataset by keeping all single ID rows coded 1 for Select AND keeping ALL multiple ID rows if ANY one of those multiple rows is coded 1 for Select for the same ID. The resulting dataset should look like:

```
ID  Position    Select
2      B          1
2      C          0
4      A          1
```

What is the best way to do this?

Ultimately, I then need to covert from long to wide form. Therefore, the final result should be:

```
ID  Position1   Position2  Select
2      B            C        1
4      A                     1
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
u = df.groupby("ID").filter(lambda x: (x.Select == 1).any())  # or just `lambda x: x.Select.any()` if there are only 0/1 values
print(u)
```

Prints:

```
   ID Position  Select
1   2        B       1
2   2        C       0
5   4        A       1
```

---

To long form:

```
u["col"] = u.groupby("ID").cumcount() + 1
s = u.groupby("ID")["Select"].any().astype(int)

u = u[["ID", "col", "Position"]].pivot(index="ID", columns="col")
u.columns = [f"{c[0]}{c[1]}" for c in u.columns]
print(pd.concat([u, s], axis=1).fillna("").reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   ID Position1 Position2  Select
0   2         B         C       1
1   4         A                 1
```